# Gwt LineChart options - make all points visible

Tags: gwt, linechart, gxt

Is there any way to set options of LineChart so that all of the points are visible, not only on the mouseover.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer - using

```
setPointSize(n);
```

works great. It makes all the points visible.